# Smart Home: controlled power receptacles

Tags: wireless, power-supply, automation, power-control, smart-device

I want to get power receptacles controlled via web and buttons.

**Specifications:**

- I need an one-room system, wireless.
- Electric power system here is bad for signal transferring. WiFi (Z Wave, ZigBee, etc), BlueTooth frequencies are fine.
- Ok price, up to 25$ per receptacle (not including other parts).
- Only on/off for controlling simple devices plugged in. Status isn't necessary.

Also, please, don't propose inflexible closed undocumented and proprietary protocols' devices. Here's "and", not "or". For example, Z Wave is proprietary but seems ok. Open source solutions which are free but are a coder's scribbles with a long dead community aren't good for me. The receptaplaces controller functional should be expandable with sensors, actuators, etc.

**Difficulty level**: mid-tier, I'm an IT guy, but not a hardware guy. 
So, no circuits' designs from scratch, please, anything from the "arduino" level is ok.

Please, give me the recommendations with a rough pricing and links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one's pretty easy, really. Pick up the **[TP-Link HS100 Wi-Fi Smart Plug](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=1208066&gclid=Cj0KEQjwxqS-BRDRgPLp0q2t0IUBEiQAgfMXRBHZrcxW-3eJ_885GaDOGn_in7D1D_AH7IdUTC4zv5IaAjkB8P8HAQ&is=REG&ap=y&m=Y&c3api=1876%2C92051677562%2C&A=details&Q=)**. It was the first device I found when I searched for "smart outlet."

- It is $25
- It is bog standard 2.4ghz wifi
- It turns stuff on and off
- It is still made and supported by TP-Link, which is a large and well-known networking products manufacturer
- It's easy to use - "[there's an app for that](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tplink.kasa_android)" as it were.

Comment: This system isn't expandable, proprietary and enclosed for a vendor with a sparse choice of smart-devices. You should forever use their app and their devices without any API. There exist a lot of known ZigBee or WiFi alternatives for just 10$, even ZWave devices pricing is very close (at least there'is an abundant smart-hardware offer).

Comment: You should probably post those devices as either an answer to your own question or as part of your question explaining why you know of them but are looking for something better.

Comment: I tried to post an info about the system I want to build at the end, but the moderator forbidden this way as "too broad." Thanks for your help. No, I haven't an answer. ZWave has a lack of API (never see it), so inflexible as TP-Link, pricing is close, choice is wider. Ready ZigBee as Xiaomy is cheap and easy, but I never tried their devices, in theory this is an open protocol, and you can control the devices from your own web server. However, at Uncle Lao's practice problems are very possible.

Comment: if it helps, there are many successful examples of people working with these smart outlets on GitHub. I'm not surprised, given how standardized they are. Proprietary or not, they shouldn't be too difficult to integrate into other systems.

Comment: Wykers Got an gitHub example link? Even the largest [Openhab]https://github.com/openhab/openhab/wiki project haven't their devices in bindings.

Comment: @Les here's another implementation: https://github.com/natefox/tplink-hs100

Comment: @Les and here's an API under active development for this plug: https://github.com/plasticrake/hs100-api

Comment: I'd been searching for a whole vendor devices' class, this is why.